# Mirror sphere on the X axis

Tags: objects, mirror, object-mode, mirror-modifier

[image]

Hi! I made the above sphere which is supposed to be a shoulder. I want to mirror it exactly to the other side of the X axis. I would also like that every changes that I make to the sphere are also made on the mirrored sphere. I've tried to use the mirror modifier but it didn't work, as I believe it only mirrors parts of an object, not the object itself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions. By default the mirror will always consider the origin of the object as the center of the mirroring. if you want to mirror the sphere at the opposite side of the Y axis you could give your sphere a *Mirror* modifier, enable the *Affect Only Origins* option, then select the origin and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> option so that the origin goes at the center of the scene, then disable the option. You could also join the sphere to the other object and give the *Mirror* to this object. In that case delete half of the object so that the half doesn't overlap with the mirrored mesh.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly!